# Request Line is too large (8192 > 4094)

Tags: django, http, nginx, web, gunicorn

I am using nginx and gunicorn to deploy my django project, when I use GET funcation posted data to server I get the error:

```
Bad Request

Request Line is too large (8192 > 4094)
```

On nginx.conf I have:

```
client_max_body_size 100g;
client_header_buffer_size 512k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 512k;
```

Many methods on the Internet are changing "large_client_header_buffers" from 4 512k; but didn't fix the problem.

Any help or explanation is welcome! Thank you.

Comment: it's related to gunicorn https://serverfault.com/a/564468

Comment: Thank you, i made it！

Comment: Do you know if there's a way we can validate it on client side with JS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is gunicorn issue, not Nginx

you can change the limit

```
--limit-request-line
```

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#limit-request-line

Comment: Thank you, i made it！